# How to insert data into a many-to-many junction table in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently, I have 4 tables:
original:

```
job | company
jobA| companyA
jobB| companyA
jobA| companyB
...
```

job-title:

```
job_id | job
1       | jobA
...
```

company:

```
company_id | company
1          | companyA
...
```

I created a junction table job_company:

```
job_company_id | job_id | company_id
```

The junction table is empty now. How can I insert correct id relations into this table?

Comment: Well, that depends on which jobs are related to which companies. In what form do you have that information?

Comment: `Select company_id,jobid from job_title j,company c where substr(j.job,LENGTH(j.job)-1,LENGTH(j.job))= substr(c.company,LENGTH(c.company)-1,LENGTH(c.company))` as per your eg how can you develop a relation without knowing how a job relates to a company specify little more in the question you are asking

Comment: There is a thing in joining tables atleast one similar  column/attribute should be there to join the two tables which are related just by saying jobA for companyA doesnt make any sense though still if this is the case you can try the above query

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I edited the question. I have an original table contains all the information of company and jobs.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres you can write an `INSERT INTO...SELECT` query that starts from the `original` table, and then JOIN with `company` and `job` to recover the relevant ids.

```
INSERT INTO job_company
SELECT o.job, c.company_id, j.job_id
FROM original o
JOIN company c on c.company = o.company
JOIN job_title j on j.job = o.job
```